# Loop though multi-dimensional array in ruby

Tags: ruby, loops, multidimensional-array

This is the question i'm having trouble with.
"**Loop through the multi-dimensional Array and print out the full information of even items in the Array (ie the 2nd and 4th array in your multidimensional array)**".I'm tasked with outputting all the data in the even numbered array which should be [1] [3], which would output all the information from array "derrick" & "andrew" only.

```
kristopher = ["kris", "palos hills", "708-200", "green"]
derrick = ["D-Rock", "New York", "773-933", "green"]
willie = ["William", "Humbolt Park", "773-987", "Black"]
andrew = ["drew", "northside", "773-123","blue"]

friends = [kristopher, derrick, willie, andrew]

friends.each do |arr|
print arr [0..4]
end

#Output

["kris", "palos hills", "708-200", "green"]["D-Rock", "New York", "773-933", "green"]["William", "Humbolt Park", "773-987", "Black"]["drew", "northside", "773-123", "blue"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```rb
kristopher = ["kris", "palos hills", "708-200", "green"]
derrick = ["D-Rock", "New York", "773-933", "green"]
willie = ["William", "Humbolt Park", "773-987", "Black"]
andrew = ["drew", "northside", "773-123","blue"]

friends = [kristopher, derrick, willie, andrew]

(1...friends.length).step(2).each do |friendIndex|
    friend = friends[friendIndex]
    print friend 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Enumerable#partition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) and [Enumerable#each_with_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) which are helpful for splitting the array by a condition on the index of elements. If you use [Integer#even?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Integer.html#method-i-even-3F) you can make a partition between even and odd indexes (`+ 1` in this case).

```
friends.partition.with_index { |_, i| (i + 1).even? }
#=> [[["D-Rock", "New York", "773-933", "green"], ["drew", "northside", "773-123", "blue"]], [["kris", "palos hills", "708-200", "green"], ["William", "Humbolt Park", "773-987", "Black"]]]
```

So, for your case, take the first element:

```
friends.partition.with_index { |_, i| (i + 1).even? }.first
```

Or you can go straight with [Enumerable#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-select):

```
friends.select.with_index { |_, i| (i + 1).even? }
```